# C++ inheritance alternatives for properties

Tags: c++, inheritance

In my C++ library I have a set of objects with no relationship between them (imagine for example the following list: car, rabbit, engine, CPU, etc...). The only common point is a member variable called speed.

So I have in many classes something like this:

```
public:
    inline int speed() {return m_speed;}
    inline void setSpeed(int speed) {m_speed=speed;}
    inline static int maxSpeed() {return 100;}
    inline static int minSpeed() {return 1;}
    ...

protected:
    int m_speed;
```

What I don't like is to repeat for every class the above declarations (and more...), since if I need a new function for speed property, I have to add it in all classes. 
I know that one solution could be to derive all classes from a base class that define that functions. But, since the classes have nothing to do one with the other, is it the right solution?! I think is not so "clean" to see all classes deriving from a base class simply to avoid functions repetition. Isn't it? Is there any other solution around?

Comment: You still have composition possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that base class is bad. All classes have common property - speed, all objects can move with some speed and share this property.
Movable objects.

Alternatively, you can create class Speed with max() and min() methods and include it in all classes (composition).

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are not unrelated : they all have a speed. Thus, making them inherit from a class representing the concept of having a speed (`HasSpeed` ?) makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfect case for inheritance. 
The classes don't need to have any other relation aside from the fact that they all fundamentally deal with a `speed` property.